# (Z3Py) declaring function

Tags: python, z3

I would like to find c and t coefficients in simple "result=x*t+c" formula for some given result/x pairs:

```
from z3 import *

x=Int('x')
c=Int('c')
t=Int('t')

s=Solver()

f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())

# x*t+c = result
# x, result = [(1,55), (12,34), (13,300)]

s.add (f(x)==(x*t+c))
s.add (f(1)==55, f(12)==34, f(13)==300)

t=s.check()
if t==sat:
    print s.model()
else:
   print t
```

... but the result is obviously wrong. I probably need to find out how to map function arguments.

How should I define function correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of define-fun in Z3 API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740556/equivalent-of-define-fun-in-z3-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion `f(x) == x*t + c` is *not* defining the function `f` for all `x`. It is just saying that the value of `f` for *the given* `x` is `x*t + c`. Z3 supports universal quantifiers. However, they are very expensive, and Z3 is not complete when a set of constraints contains universal quantifiers since the problem becomes undecidable. That is, Z3 may return `unknown` for this kind of problem.

Note that `f` is essentially a "macro" in your script. Instead of using a Z3 function for encoding this "macro", we can create a Python function that does the trick. That is, a Python function that, given a Z3 expression, returns a new Z3 expression. Here is a new script. The script is also available online at: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Yoi
Here is another version of the script where `c` and `t` are `Real` instead of `Int`: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/uZl

```
from z3 import *

c=Int('c')
t=Int('t')

def f(x):
    return x*t + c

# data is a list of pairs (x, r)
def find(data):
    s=Solver()
    s.add([ f(x) == r for (x, r) in data ])
    t = s.check()
    if s.check() == sat:
        print s.model()
    else:
        print t

find([(1, 55)])
find([(1, 55), (12, 34)])
find([(1, 55), (12, 34), (13, 300)])
```

Remark: In the SMT 2.0 front-end, macros can be defined using the command `define-fun`.