# use of define-fun in z3's input language

Tags: z3

Going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740556/equivalent-of-define-fun-in-z3-api) post, `define-fun` seems to be a macro that gets expanded by z3's preprocessor and not seen by the actual solver but makes the input file possibly compact and easier to read. I'm asking because I see some (apparently random) differences in the satisfying assignments and performance on the same problem: one which uses `define-fun`and one which doesn't, which makes me wonder if it is more than just a macro. Does one have to be careful about the aggressive use of `define-fun` in certain cases? I observed this on some QF_NIRA, QF_LIRA problems that I have.

Answer (score 0):

define-fun is treated as a macro in Z3.
The behavior of Z3 will be different if you use equalities and uninterpreted functions.
Furthermore, if you use "declare-fun" and then create quantified equalities, 
the problem is no longer in the QF_LIRA fragment.