# Z3 Java API - ignoring an expression like a max-function

Tags: java, z3

last time I asked how to define a function in the Z3 Java API. The reason was that there is no command to define a function in the Java API. The answer was to substitute the argument values of the function for the input values ([Z3 Java API defining a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172230/z3-java-api-defining-a-function)).

Example (what I need):

**1. without API (normal smt-file)**

```
(declare-fun a () Int)
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun c () Int)
(define-fun max2 ((x Int) (y Int)) Int (ite (<= x y) y x))

(assert (< (max2 a b) c))
(assert (>= (max2 a b) c))

(check-sat)
```

What I do now is something like this:

**2. with Java API**

```
Context ctx = new Context();

ArithExpr a = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("a"), ctx.getIntSort());
ArithExpr b = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("b"), ctx.getIntSort());
ArithExpr c = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("c"), ctx.getIntSort());

ArithExpr max2 = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkITE(ctx.mkLe(a, b), b, a);
BoolExpr one = (BoolExpr) ctx.mkLt(max2, c);
BoolExpr two = (BoolExpr) ctx.mkGe(max2, c);
```

I wonder, if this makes a difference?

I assume that the max2-function in the smt-file (1) is correct and does not have to be re-solved again. But if I do it as in the above java code (2), the solver has to solve the expression of the max2-function **ctx.mkITE(ctx.mkLe(a, b), b, a)** every time again. Or am I completely wrong and it is not possible, to ignore the expression of the max2-function?

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The define-fun construct behaves like a macro, so all occurrences of max2 will be replaced with the function definition. Alternatively, we could use quantifiers and the macro-finder (see e.g., [Equivalent of define-fun in Z3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740556/equivalent-of-define-fun-in-z3-api)), or we can just replace all occurrences of the function ourselves.

In general it is not possible to "ignore" anything and Z3 will not attempt to "solve" one function before another one; it only knows one problem in which the same sub-expression can appear multiple times (and it has hash-consing, so it knows about equal sub-expressions). If you know that it's possible to solve the problem without knowing about the semantics of the function, then you could just replace it with a new variable to represent the return value for some particular arguments, that will likely make it possible to solve the problem much quicker.